Possible Generalization of the Fubini-Study Metric on the Holomorphic Vector Bundles of $\mathbb{P}_\mathbb{C}^n$
Let $X$ be the total space of the locally free sheaf $\bigoplus_{j=1}^{r} \mathcal{O}_{\mathbb{P}_{\mathbb{C}}^{n}}(-d_j)$, where $d_j$'s are positive integers. In other words, $X$ can be described as the quotient space
$$
\frac{(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbb{C}^r}{\mathbb{C}^\times}
$$
where the action is given as
$$
\lambda\cdot(z_0,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r) = (\lambda z_0,\ldots,\lambda z_n,\lambda^{-d_1} p_1,\ldots,\lambda^{-d_r}p_r).
$$
Let $Y$ be the surface with the real dimension $2n-1$ inside $\mathbb{C}^n\times \mathbb{C}^r$ defined by the equation
$$
|z_0|^2+\cdots+|z_r|^2 = d_1|p_1|^2+\cdots+d_r|p_r|^2+1.
$$
By the nature of this equality, $(z_1,\ldots,z_n)\neq 0$. Then there is $U(1)$-action on $Y$ defined by
$$
e^{i\theta}\cdot (z_0,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r) = (e^{i\theta}z_0,\ldots,e^{i\theta}z_n,e^{-id_1\theta}p_1,\ldots,e^{-id_r\theta}p_r).
$$
If $N$ is the unit normal vector of the surface $Y$, the vector tangent to the $U(1)$-orbit satisfies
$$
\frac{\partial_\theta}{\|\partial_\theta\|}=JN,
$$
where $J$ is the (almost) complex structure on the ambient space.
I observed that there is a quotient map along the $U(1)$-action, $Y\to X,$ where $(z_0,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r)$ is simply mapped to the equivalence class $[z_0,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r]$ with respect to $\mathbb{C}^\times$-action. This is a homeomorphism since for each point $[z_1,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r]$, there is a unique positive real number $\lambda$ so that $\lambda^{-1}\cdot(z_1,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r)$ satisfies the defining equation of $Y$,
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda^2}(|z_0|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2)=1+d_1\lambda^{2d_1}|p_1|^2+\cdots+d_r \lambda^{2d_r} |p_r|^2.
$$
$Y$ is equipped with the Riemannian metric inherited from its ambient space, and $U(1)$-action is clearly the isometry, so we can define the Riemannian metric on $X$.
I am trying to write the metric explicitly, but I am keep failing writing the horizontal lift of $T_p X$ in $T_q Y$.
My questions:
(1) How can I write this metric explicitly? For example, how is the metric computed on the affine open subset defined by $z_0\neq 0$? I tried to use some coordinate systems on $Y$ and $X$, but the computations were so messy.
(2) Is this metric Kähler? I am somewhat positive with this question, since we already have $\partial_{\theta}/\|\partial_{\theta}\|=JN$. To be precise, indeed there is an almost complex structure on $Y/U(1)$ that is compatible with the metric on $Y$, but I am not sure that it is the complex structure of $X$.
Thanks in advance.

The total space of a vector bundle over a compact Kahler manifold is Kahler, because it is a subspace of the projective bundle $\mathbb{P}(E \oplus \mathbb C) \to X$, which is Kahler by Kodaira. The projective bundle gets the Fubini-Study metric that a metric on the bundle induces on the fibers plus the metric pulled back from the base. Is this that metric?

@GunnarÞórMagnússon It is highly unlikely. The metric you mentioned must be incomplete, since it is an open dense submanifold inside a compact Kahler manifold. Meanwhile, the metric I defined is itself complete as a noncompact manifold. However, I presume there might be a relationship between them. As an oversimplification, what is the relationship between the Fubini Study metric on $\mathbb{P}^n$ the Euclidean metric on $\mathbb{C}^{n}$? I think there must be a relationship, regarding how geodesics goes to geodesics via $\mathbb{C}^n\to \mathbb{P}^n$, but I don’t have an answer.

I managed to finish the proof myself.
(1) Computation of the metric on the affine piece: The map $Y\to X$ is actually induced from the quotient map
$$
(\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbb{C}^r\to X.
$$
Restricting this map to the subset $z_0\neq 0$, we obtain a map $$\mathbb{C}^\times \times \mathbb{C}^n \times \mathbb{C}^r \to \mathbb{C}^{n+r},
\\(z_0,z_1,\ldots,z_n,p_1,\ldots,p_r) \mapsto (z_1/z_0,\ldots,z_n/z_0,z_0^{d_1}p_1,\ldots,z_0^{d_r}p_r).
$$
We let $Z_1,\cdots,Z_n,P_1,\ldots,P_r$ be the holomorphic coordinate for $\mathbb{C}^{n+r}$. Hence we have the following maps on the tangent space,
$$
z_0\partial_{z_0}\mapsto -\sum_{j=1}^nZ_j\partial_{Z_j}+\sum_{k=1}^r d_k P_k\partial_{P_k},\\
z_j\partial_{z_j} \mapsto Z_j \partial_{Z_j}, \\
p_j\partial_{p_j} \mapsto P_j \partial_{P_j}.
$$
One can check the vector $\nabla F$ and $J\nabla F$, where $$F=|z_0|^2+\cdots+|z_n|^2-d_1|p_1|^2-\cdots-d_r|p_r|^2$$ is the defining function for $Y$, is in the kernel of the map. Hence, $T_p Y \to T_{\pi(p)} X$ is actually defined by the following composition
$$
Y \hookrightarrow (\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus \{0\})\times\mathbb{C}^r \to X.
$$
For each point $(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n,P_1,\ldots,P_r)$ in $\{z_0\neq 0\} \subset X$, we have the unique positive real number $\lambda(Z_1,\ldots,Z_n,P_1,\ldots,P_r)$ satisfying
$$
1+|Z_1|^2+\cdots+|Z_n|^2 = \lambda^2 + d_1\lambda^{2d_1+2}|P_1|^2 +\cdots + d_r\lambda^{2d_r+2}|P_r|^2.
$$
By the above computation of $d\pi$, we have the lift
$$
\frac{1}{\lambda} \partial_{z_j}\mapsto \partial_{Z_j},\\
\lambda^{d_j}\partial_{p_j}\mapsto \partial_{P_j}.
$$
To compute the metric, we only need to compute the bilinear form defined by $I-\frac{(\nabla F) (\nabla F)^T  - (J\nabla F)(J \nabla F)^T}{(\nabla F)^T (\nabla F)}$.
(2) The metric is compatible with the complex structure on $X$: this is obvious once we again observe that the quotient map is composition,
$$
Y\to (\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbb{C}^r\to X,
$$
which induces the map on the tangent space,
$$
H_p Y \to T_p (\mathbb{C}^{n+1}\setminus\{0\})\times \mathbb{C}^r \to T_{\pi(p)}X.
$$
Thus, indeed the complex structure $J$ on $T_{\pi(p)}X$ and $H_p Y$ must coincide. In other words, we have
$$
(JV)^h= J(V^h).
$$
for any vector field $V$ on $X$.
(3) The metric is Kahler. Easy way to do this is to prove that $J$ is flat with respect to the Levi-Civita connection. We have the following formula,
$$
\nabla^Y_{V^h}W^h -\frac{1}{2}v[V^h,W^h] = (\nabla^X_V W)^h.
$$
or simply,
$$
d\pi(\nabla^Y_{V^h}W^h) = \nabla^X_V W.
$$
Since $JN$ is the vertical component, we have
$$
d\pi (JV)^h = Jd\pi(V^h).
$$
If we put $JW$ to the equation,
$$
d\pi(\nabla^X_V (JW))^h = Jd\pi(\nabla^X_V (W))^h.
$$
